# How should the structure be built for Firebase Requests

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, callback, firebase-authentication

Brief information: I am working on a quiz application for Android. The database is on Firebase and the users login via anonymously. When the user opened the application, it will be automatically signed-in.

My question is about firebase. I could not build the intelligence for firebase requests.

When the application is opened; 
1) signInAnonymously (which firebase function) should be called first. 
2) Then i check that the signed user has a saved point or not on firebase database. 
3) If the user does not have point, it is generated.
4) Then i send a request to get the point of user.

In all steps, i send a request to firebase via async firebase methods. The sequence is important because the output of any step can be an input for the next step.

I handle this via callback. But i do not know that it is the best way.

[screenshots of callbacks for these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpR3Q.png)

Can you give me advice for these? If i do not use callbacks, problems are occured because of asynchronous firebase methods. The reason of that i open this issue is undetermined problems. I can learn and build any other algorithm to make it better. Thank you.

Comment: Please refrain from using screenshots for code, you can just paste the code itself in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using nested callbacks and I am not a Java programmer, but you may want to take it easy on yourself and not go that route.

If my signing in anonymously you mean a One-Time-Password authentication flow such as just providing a phone number, that would definitely be a good approach.

You can use Google Cloud Functions, but the functions would have to be written in Nodejs, Python or Go.

Either way take a look at this flow below:

1. User requests OTP
2. Acknowledge the request
3. Generate code, save the code on backend (GCF)
4. Text user the code
5. User sends you the correct code
6. Compare codes on the server
7. Send user some kind of token or as you say a "point" to identify them.

I do believe Java does have support for JSON Web Tokens.

So after your setup GCF project, you are going to get some folder and files like so:

`.firebaserc`: a hidden file that helps you quickly switch between projects with firebase use.

`firebase.json`: describes properties for your project.

`functions/`: this folder contains all the code for your functions.

`functions/package.json`: an NPM package file describing your Cloud Functions.

`functions/index.js`: the main source for your Cloud Functions code.

`functions/node_modules/`: the folder where all your NPM dependencies are installed.

You want to import the needed modules and initialize the app:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

That `service_account.json` is something you need to create, its not a library.

It will have a bunch of private and public keys that you get from your Firebase console. Ensure you also place that file inside your `.gitignore` files as well.

So I am skipping some crucial details here that you will have to figure out so as to get to your main question.

First, you need the idea of a user, so you need to create a user inside GCF so that in itself is going to be a function and as you mentioned Firebase is asynchronous so it would look something like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  // Verify the user provided a phone
  if (!req.body.phone) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: "Bad Input" });
  }

  // Format the phone number to remove dashes and parens
  const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

  // Create a new user account using that phone number
  admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({ uid: phone })
    .then(user => res.send(user))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).send({ error: err }));

  // Respond to user request saying account was made
};
```

So the code above I grabbed from a previous project of mine, except the whole thing was in JavaScript. For you this part will be in JavaScript or Nodejs specifically as well since again, Nodejs, Go or Python are the only languages supported by GCF.

So the comments are self-explanatory but I feel compelled to explain that the first thing I had to resolve is how to pass in information to this function in a request.

To do that I had to reference the `req.body` object as you see above. `req.body` contains all the different data that was passed to this function when the user called it. I was not sure if you knew that. So before you go and copy paste what I have above, do a `res.send(req.body);`. So nothing else inside that `module.exports = function(req, res) {}` except `res.send(req.body);`, so you can get a good sense of how this all works.

For every function you create you need to run a `firebase deploy name-of-project`.

After you feel you have a handle on this and its all working successfully, you can create your Android Studio project and add the database dependency like so:

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'`

And then you will probably want to create your User model, maybe like this:

```
public class User {

    public String phone;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

And so on, anyway I hope that kind of gives you a good enough idea that it gets you going. Best of luck. I know I failed to take time out to explain that the regex in my code is to sanitize the phone number and probably some other stuff. So again, don't just copy paste what I offered, study it.